# showing that $\binom{m^{3}}{m+1}= \binom{m^{3}}{m}\cdot(m^2-m)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I have a problem.

$$\binom{m^{3}}{m+1}= \binom{m^{3}}{m}\cdot(m^2-m)$$

I don't know what to do to make the right side equal with left. 
Everytime I do that it doesn't work.
 Step by step explanation please!

Right side: (m^3!)/(m!(m^3-m))! * (m^2-m)

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have you tried anything? You could start with the definition of the binomial coefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could break down the binomial coefficients into factorials. So you are trying to show:

$$\frac{(m^3)!}{(m+1)!(m^3-m-1)!}=\frac{(m^3)!}{m!(m^3-m)!}\cdot(m^2-m)$$

If you divide on both sides by $m^3-m$, you make the second factor in the left denominator match the second factor in the right denominator:

$$\frac{(m^3)!}{(m+1)!(m^3-m-1)!(m^3-m)}=\frac{(m^3)!}{m!(m^3-m)!}\cdot\frac{(m^2-m)}{m^3-m}$$
$$\frac{(m^3)!}{(m+1)!(m^3-m)!}=\frac{(m^3)!}{m!(m^3-m)!}\cdot\frac{(m^2-m)}{m^3-m}$$

If you multiply on each side by $m+1$, you do the same with the first factor of the denominator:

$$\frac{(m+1)(m^3)!}{(m+1)!(m^3-m)!}=\frac{(m^3)!}{m!(m^3-m)!}\cdot\frac{(m^2-m)(m+1)}{m^3-m}$$
$$\frac{(m^3)!}{m!(m^3-m)!}=\frac{(m^3)!}{m!(m^3-m)!}\cdot\frac{(m^2-m)(m+1)}{m^3-m}$$

Now what does that fraction on the far right simplify to?

Note that all of the equations here are equivalent, since we only ever multiplied/divided by nonzero quantities.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had it today in class but lecturer wanted us to do it differently. I tried to do it like he said and it didn't work. I tried to transform right side in that way to receive left side - what will prove that left is equal right side. By the way sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\binom{a}{m}$ and $\binom{a}{m+1}$.
By definition, we have that
$$
\binom{a}{m+1} = \frac{a\times (a-1)\times \cdots\times (a-m)}{(m+1)\times m\times\cdots 1}.
$$
Similarly,
$$
\binom{a}{m} = \frac{a\times (a-1)\times\cdots\times (a-m+1)}{m\times (m-1)\times \cdots\times 1}.
$$
Compare the two expressions. We have that
$$
\binom{a}{m+1} = \frac{a-m}{m+1}\binom{a}{m}.
$$
Now take $a=m^3$ you get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can't think of it combinatorically.
${m^3}\choose{m+1}$ is the number of ways of choosing $m+1$ objects from the set of $m^3$ objects and the order doesn't matter.
On the other hand, it's the same as first choosing $m$ objects, which is ${m^3}\choose{m}$ and then choosing one object from the remaining ones, which is $m^3-m$. But you counted the same set $m+1$ times, so you divide  ${m^3}\choose{m}$$(m^3-m)$ by $m+1$, which simplifies to ${m^3}\choose{m}$$(m^2-m)$, the right side of the given identity.

Answer (score 0):

Expand the wrong side:
$C_{m^3}^{m+1}=\frac{(m^3)!}{(m+1)! \cdot (m^3-m-1)!}$

Do the same with right side:
$C_{m^3} ^{m} \cdot (m^2-m)=\frac{(m^3)!}{m! \cdot (m^3-m)!} \cdot (m^2-m)=C_{m^3}^ {m+1}\cdot \frac{m+1}{m^3-m}\cdot (m^2-m)=C_{m^3}^ {m+1}(\therefore)$

There you go: right is left. Or wrong. Same thing.